# Shoulda Matcher with custom validation causing all shoulda validations to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

I am running into a problem where a custom validation on my model is causing all of the shoulda validations to fail.

Essentially:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validate :some_date_validation

  private

  def some_date_validation
    if date_given > birthday
      errors.add(:birthday, "Some sort of error message")
    end
  end
end
```

And then in the spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe "shoulda validations" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  end
end
```

This will cause my test to fail because the other validation won't pass. Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to test using an instance of an object which is valid by default.

When you use the implicit subject in your Rspec test, Rspec will create a new instance of the object under test for you using the default initializer. In this case, `User.new`. This instance will be invalid because neither `name` is present nor is the custom validation going to pass.

If you are using factories (e.g. `factory_girl`) then you should create a `User` factory which sets all the attributes which make the validations pass.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "John Doe"
    date_given Time.now
    birthday 25.years.ago
  end
end
```

Then use it in your tests

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe "shoulda validations" do
    subject { build(:user) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  end
end
```

You've now explicitly set the subject of your tests to be a new instance of `User` created by your factory. The attributes will be pre-set which means your instance is valid by default, and the tests should now be able to test each individual validation properly.

Comment: I think my example wasn't the best. This validation I'm working with is calling for a field on a different object. I guess I just need to create a valid nested object in the factory with this. I think this helped though, thank you.